# C# List item values are inconsistent

Tags: c#

I am adding values to my list, and it overrides to the previous value with the newly assigned value. I guess this has something to do with reference type and value types.

```
class EODSales
{
    public string Sales { get; set; }
    public int TC { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

class EODBO
{
    public string Sales { get; set; }

    public List<EODSales> Values { get; set; }
}
.
.
.
.
List<EODSales> EODSalesList = new List<EODSales>();
List<EODBO> eodboList = new List<EODBO>();
.
.
.
//Inside a method - 

EODSales sales = new EODSales();
sales.Sales = "Prev";
sales.TC = 5;
sales.Amount = 500;
EODSalesList.Add(sales);

EODBO obj = new EODBO();
obj.Sales = "Baking Order";
obj.Values = EODSalesList;
eodboList.Add(obj);


//Inside another method 
EODSales sales = new EODSales();
sales.Sales = "Prev";
sales.TC = 10;
sales.Amount = 1000;
EODSalesList.Add(sales);

EODBO obj = new EODBO();
obj.Sales = "Refund";
obj.Values = EODSalesList;
eodboList.Add(obj);
```

I'm expecting that my eodboList to be like: My first item in the list has Sales = "Baking Order" and values have "Prev", 5, and 500. While my 2nd item in the list has Sales = "Refund" and values have "Prev", 10, and 100 respectively.
My current code just assigns EODBO.Values to all the other item in the list, meaning that my first item Baking Order has values of "Prev", 10, and 100.

UPDATE
I changed my Values in EODBO to 
public EODSales Values { get; set; }
Here is my code
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dHNr9o

Comment: This is kind-of unclear, can you perhaps take some times to better explain what you want and what is not working, and desired output

Comment: Maybe take this and put it into a simple console app that demonstrates it and share the code?

Comment: I overlooked something, I just solved this a few seconds ago. I'm going to share my solution in a few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using *EODSalesList* for all of items in *eodboList*,quick fix :

```
class EODSales
{
    public string Sales { get; set; }
    public int TC { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

class EODBO
{
    public string Sales { get; set; }

    public List<EODSales> Values { get; set; }
}
.
.
.
.
List<EODSales> EODSalesList = new List<EODSales>();
List<EODBO> eodboList = new List<EODBO>();
.
.
.
//Inside a method - 

EODSales sales = new EODSales();
sales.Sales = "Prev";
sales.TC = 5;
sales.Amount = 500;
EODSalesList.Add(sales);
List<EODSales> localEODSalesList = new List<EODSales>();
localEODSalesList.Add(sales);

EODBO obj = new EODBO();
obj.Sales = "Baking Order";
obj.Values = localEODSalesList;
eodboList.Add(obj);


//Inside another method 

EODSales sales = new EODSales();
sales.Sales = "Prev";
sales.TC = 10;
sales.Amount = 1000;
EODSalesList.Add(sales);
List<EODSales> localEODSalesList = new List<EODSales>();
localEODSalesList.Add(sales);


EODBO obj = new EODBO();
obj.Sales = "Baking Order";
obj.Values = localEODSalesList;
eodboList.Add(obj);
```

Comment: Turns out my previous solution was wrong. This is what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: np, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
 You have to change your code  as like 
 below:
      // First Method
        EODSales sales = new EODSales();

        sales.Sales = "Prev";
        sales.TC = 5;
        sales.Amount = 500;
        EODSalesList.Add(sales);

        EODBO obj = new EODBO();
        obj.Sales = "Baking Order";
        obj.Values.Add(sales);
        eodboList.Add(obj);

Same way, You have change into second method:

replace obj.Values=sales  to obj.Values.Add(sales)
```

Comment: Here's what I did
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dHNr9o